# foreign key syntax in the below code is not working and it comes an error in creating the table

Tags: mysql, rdbms

This is a DBMS query in MySQL of Ubuntu.

```
create table Advisor(s_id varchar(5),
                     i_id varchar(5),
                     primary key(s_id),
                     foreign key(i_id)references instructor(id),
                     foreign key(s_id)references student(id)
                    );
```

Comment: "it comes an error" - Please copy that error message in your post.

Comment: The syntax is correct. SO either instructor or student tables don't have an `id` field that is `PRIMARY` or index